# Value and Index of MAX in each column of matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm aware of:

```
id,value = max(enumerate(trans_p), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

I'm trying to find something equivalent for matrices, where I'm looking for the *value* and *row index* of the max **for each column** of the matrix

so the function could take in any matrix, such as:

```
np.array([[0,0,1],[2,0,0],[5,0,0]])
```

and return two vectors: a vector of row numbers where the max is found, and the max values themselves - for each column. I'm trying to avoid a for-loop! Ideally the function returns two values, like that:

```
rowIdVect, maxVect = ...........
```

where the values for the example matrix above would be:

```
[2,0,0]  #rowIdVect
[5,0,1]  #maxVect
```

I can do this in two steps:

```
idVect = np.argmax( myMat , axis=0)
maxVect = np.max( trans_probs_mat, axis=0)
```

But is there a syntax that would perform both at the same time? **Note**: I'm trying to improve run times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index to find the corresponding values:

```
In [201]: arr=np.array([[0,0,1],[2,0,0],[5,0,0]])
In [202]: idx=np.argmax(arr, axis=0)
In [203]: np.max(arr, axis=0)
Out[203]: array([5, 0, 1])
In [204]: arr[idx,np.arange(3)]
Out[204]: array([5, 0, 1])
```

Is this worth it?  I doubt if the use of `argmax` and/or `max` is a bottleneck in your calculations.  But feel free to time test with realistic data.